# Layered background images fail to render when window is scaled large in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, performance, google-chrome, background-image

This part of the code is supposed to show an area with multiple overlapping images. Each layer has a set of image options, so layers can be mixed.

**Problem:**
I have a problem with these overlapping images in Chrome. They are positioned absolute and with set z-indexes. They show as expected in "normal" browser size but when increasing the area for these images some disappear and show white blocks. This only occurs in Chrome. I want to make sure this is future proof for large displays.

I am using GPU acceleration with -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) to speed up the app. Removing this makes all layers show even on large window size in chrome. However, this slows the app down and does not fix the whole problem. This makes me want to keep the transform translate. When transform translate is off, layer images still disappear and show white when switching (even some of the layers that were not swithched) image for one layer.

Only the currently shown image layers are included in the DOM, and when one is switched a clone of the just recent image layer is shown in front while loading the newly selected image layer behind.

The image sizes are 2048px by 1344px on large screens and scaled to fit the window (but not beyond that). I relize this might be heavy performance-wise, but it works perfect in Firefox and IE. I am thankful for any response.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

   <div id="layer-1" class="layer" style="z-index: 1;">
      <div class="layer-option" style="background-image: url(layer1-option1.png);"></div>
      <div class="clone" style="background-image: url(layer1-option1.png);"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="layer-2" class="layer" style="z-index: 2;">
      <div class="layer-option" style="background-image: url(layer2-option1.png);"></div>
      <div class="clone" style="background-image: url(layer2-option1.png);"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="layer-3" class="layer" style="z-index: 3;">
      <div class="layer-option" style="background-image: url(layer3-option1.png);"></div>
      <div class="clone" style="background-image: url(layer3-option1.png);"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="layer-4" class="layer" style="z-index: 4;">
      <div class="layer-option" style="background-image: url(layer4-option1.png);"></div>
      <div class="clone" style="background-image: url(layer4-option1.png);"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="layer-5" class="layer" style="z-index: 5;">
      <div class="layer-option" style="background-image: url(layer5-option1.png);"></div>
      <div class="clone" style="background-image: url(layer5-option1.png);"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="layer-6" class="layer" style="z-index: 6;">
      <div class="layer-option" style="background-image: url(layer6-option1.png);"></div>
      <div class="clone" style="background-image: url(layer6-option1.png);"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="layer-7" class="layer" style="z-index: 7;">
      <div class="layer-option" style="background-image: url(layer7-option1.png);"></div>
      <div class="clone" style="background-image: url(layer7-option1.png);"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="layer-8" class="layer" style="z-index: 8;">
      <div class="layer-option" style="background-image: url(layer8-option1.png);"></div>
      <div class="clone" style="background-image: url(layer8-option1.png);"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="layer-9" class="layer" style="z-index: 9;">
      <div class="layer-option" style="background-image: url(layer9-option1.png);"></div>
      <div class="clone" style="background-image: url(layer9-option1.png);"></div>
   </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.layer {
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   bottom: 0;
   top: 0;
   background-size:100%;
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);   
}

.layer layer-option {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-size:100%;
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);  
}
```